# Simple CASE expression in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. I am trying to practice writing CASE expressions. Below is a query I have been working with.

```
SELECT bill, 
       'provider' as
       case 
              when refer != '' THEN refer 
              WHEN render != '' THEN render 
              ELSE 'NULL' 
              END
              FROM   billing
```

This is the criteria for my query -

1) I need a new column in the select that is not part of the table. I have named it `provider` in the above query.

2) I need the new column's value to be the refer column's value if refer is not empty.

3) I need it to be equal to the render column's value if render is not empty.

4) I need it to be NULL if both are empty.

5) The output should look like

```
Bill  Provider
123   Health
456   Org
789   NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT bill, 
       (CASE WHEN refer <> '' THEN refer 
             WHEN render <> '' THEN render 
        END) as provider
FROM  billing;
```

Notes:

- The column alias comes *after* the definition.
- Although `!=` works, `<>` is the tradition comparison operator for not equals.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use them for string and date constants.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got a fine answer, but I figured I'd mention a few other commands to investigate while you're learning about CASE. They may not apply to your current problem, but you'll likely find over time that FILTER and COALESCE are equally worth knowing about. FILTER often works as a simpler-to-read alternative to CASE. Check it out while you're CASE, and you'll have another option for future problems. Here's a short write-up you might like:

https://medium.com/little-programming-joys/the-filter-clause-in-postgres-9-4-3dd327d3c852

I use FILTER for manually constructed pivot tables, and it's *much* simpler to construct and review in that situation.

COALESCE you may already know about. But, if not, it's super handy. Pass in a list of possible values, and get back the first one (reading left-to-right) that's not null. That can sometimes be what you need where you would otherwise have to write a CASE.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html